# Can animals perceive screens?

Tags: usability, users

Since the RGB scheme and refresh rates are designed with the human visual system in mind, what do other animals see when they look at screens?

Can they see just as well as us? Can they see the image, but with less saturation or different colors?

Comment: Not really usability topic material but a funny question that I had to answer.

Comment: My dog's interest in a moving mouse cursor on the TV says yes.

Comment: what if my users are animals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this answer at Biology StackExchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/why-can-cats-interpret-things-on-a-monitor-tv-but-dogs-cannot):

> **Cats and dogs can both view tv screens & monitors** ... though their viewing experience is a little different to ours thanks to differences
>   in cone structure leaving them [color blind and giving low acuity](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/why-can-cats-interpret-things-on-a-monitor-tv-but-dogs-cannot).

From sciencenordic.com:

> "We humans need about 16 to 20 images a second to perceive what we see
>   as continuous film, whereas dogs need about 70 images per second.
>
> So a few years ago, Fido was probably confounded by his master's
>   behaviour of sitting for hours staring at a flashing succession of
>   images. With modern resolution and quicker imaging, dogs have become
>   potential television viewers.
>
> This has not gone unrecognized in the USA, for example, where hopeful
>   TV producers have started special TV channels for dogs.
>
> If you have other pets, however, you need to think twice before
>   placing them in front of the TV.
>
> Birds need at least 100 frames per second to see TV images as a moving
>   picture. Having a bird in the same room as a TV with a lower frame
>   rate than that will be very stressful for the creature."

Comment: We had a dog barking at the bear on the giant CRT.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, I have seen a dog watch TV very intently.

I have a close friend with 2 Boston Terriers, a male and a female. They look like this:

[image: Your typical Boston Terrier, a furry terrestrial catfish with legs]

(Image credit: [ASPCA](https://www.aspcapetinsurance.com/blog/2017/april/03/fun-facts-about-boston-terriers/))

Their male Boston has a very interesting reaction to the television. It doesn't really react to people, but when **animals of any kind** - real, animated or cartoon dogs, birds, seals, stuffed animals - appear on screen, it immediately hops up on the furniture near the TV, turns its head to look out the corner of its eye and growls menacingly until the animal leaves the screen.

It cracks me up, but they're used to it.